# Matlab simscape component modification.

Tags: matlab

I am new to Matlab. I wanted to use Simscape resistor element and want to make it Temperature dependent. However i open the code of the component by view source code. I modify the code but couldn't save it. It gives only option to save as "Save as" . If i save as to new .ssc file then i cannot run that code to generate the component either. Your suggestions and opinion regarding this issue will be appreciated. 
Thank you!!

Answer (score 1):

There are three steps that are required to include a custom simscape component into simulink

1. Suitable directory tree structure

Simscape expects component source to be listed in a directory structure prepended with "+" and within the MATLAB search path ( file --> set path)

Take for instance **/home/USER/Documents/MATLAB** is listed in the MATLAB path search list, I can create a custom simscape file hierarchy from here:

**/home/USER/Documents/MATLAB/+custom**

Within this new directory I can save my simscape part

2. Build the simscape part.

With a valid Simscape structure existing, a library part can be "compiled" via the ssc_build command

**ssc_build +custom**

where +custom is the structure that was created. This will create within **/home/USER/Documents/MATLAB/** a custom_lib.mdl file, a valid Simulink library that can be opened & your custom part dragged out

3. Adding a custom library to the main library browser

For this to work a slblocks.m file is required

```
function blkStruct = slblocks
        % This function specifies that the library should appear
        % in the Library Browser
        % and be cached in the browser repository

        Browser.Library = 'custom_lib';
        % 'mylib' is the name of the library

        Browser.Name = 'My Library';
        % 'My Library' is the library name that appears in the Library Browser

        blkStruct.Browser = Browser;
```

http://uk.mathworks.com/help/simulink/ug/adding-libraries-to-the-library-browser.html

Your user library and custom part will now appear in the simulink browser

Comment: Thank you JonRB for your time and suggestions. Your suggestion worked for me, apart from including '+' sign for compiling using command **ssc_build custom** no + sign required for my Matlab version 2014 and 2015.